# Сортировка рваного двумерного массива

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class Twoarrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "Несортированный";
    int[][] array = new int [5] [];
    for(int s = 0;s < array.length;s++) {
        int y = 2 + (int) (8*Math.random());
        array[s] = new int[y];
        }
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                text += "\n";
                for(int k = 0; k < array[i].length;k++) {
                    array [i] [k] = (int) (8* Math.random());
                    text += array [i] [k] + " ";
        }
      }
    text+= "\n";
    text += "После сортировки";
    boolean start = false;
    boolean start1 = false;
    while(!start && !start1) {
        start = true;
        start1 = true;
        for(int i = 0; i > array.length - 1; i++) {
            text += "\n";
            for(int j = 0;j > array[i].length;i++) {
                if(array[i] [j] > array[i+1] [j]) {
                    int[] [] b = new int[1] [];
                    b= array;
                    array[i+1][j] = array[i] [j];
                    array [i] [j] = b[i+1] [j];
                    start = false;
                }
            }
        }
                    for(int i = 0;i < array.length-1;i++) {
                        for(int j = 0;j < array[i].length-1;j++) {
                            int[] [] b = new int[1] [];
                            b = array;
                            array[i] [j+1] = array[i] [j];
                            array[i] [j] = b [i] [j+1];
                            start1 = false;
                    } 
                }
            }
    System.out.println(text);
        }
}
```

Вывода, почему-то нет.
Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать рабочий код и укажите на мои ошибки!

Comment: while(!start1)  код не выходит из этого цикла

Comment: Немного подкорректировал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не кажется, что в этом решении черт ногу сломит? Код сначала должен быть читаемым... Может стоит попробовать другой подход

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Twoarrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //создание массива
        int[][] array = new int[5][];
        //создание массива
        for (int s = 0; s < array.length; s++) array[s] = new int[2+(int)(8*Math.random())];
        //выхов метода "iterateAndSet", в аргументах передается созданные выше массив (первый агрумент)
        //и лямбда выражение, которое определено стандартным интерфейсом (входит в состав java core c 8 версии)
        //Supplier<Integer> (второй агрумент). суть лямбды в том, что вы можете передать в аргументы метода не состояние (паременную),
        //а поведение (по сути сам метод). ()->(int) (8 * Math.random()) - это означает метод, который не принимает параметров (пустые скобки перед стрелкой-> ),
        //а возвращает рандомный инт (выражение после стрелки ->)
        iterateAndSet(array, ()->(int) (8 * Math.random()));

        //аналогично выражению System.out.println - вывод в консоль. 
        //поскольку вывод в консоль вызывается часто сделан статический импорт import static java.lang.System.out;
        //теперь переменная out импортирована и System можно не писать
        out.println("Несортированный: ");
        //выхов метода "iterate", в аргументах передается созданные выше массив (первый агрумент)
        //и лямбда выражение, которое определено стандартным интерфейсом (входит в состав java core c 8 версии)
        //Consumer<Integer> (второй агрумент). i->out.print(i+" ") - это означает метод, который принимает переменную типа Integer, 
        //определенную сигнатурой интерфейса, (i перед стрелкой-> ), и ничего не возвращает, 
        //при этом выводит в консоль перемную i, которую передали в аргументач - i->out.print(i+" ") (выражение после стрелки ->)
        iterate(array, i->out.print(i+" "));
        //аналогично out.println("Несортированный: ");
        out.println("\r\nСортированный: ");
        //аналогично iterate(array, i->out.print(i+" ")), однако массив мередается сначала в метод sort, который возвращает уже отнсортированный массив
        iterate(sort(array), i->out.print(i+" "));

    }

    //метод, который непосредственно осуществляет сортировку 
    private static int[][] sort(int[][] arr) {
        //создается коллекция Integer
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        //аналогично iterate(array, i->out.print(i+" ")); разница лишь в том, что переменная i теперь не выводится в консоль, 
        //а добавляется в созданную коллекцию
        iterate(arr, i->list.add(i));
        //на предыдущем шаге все элементы массива добавлены в коллекцию, теперь они сортируются        
        list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        //коллекция вызывает итератор, который позволяет перебрать все элементы коллекции
        Iterator <Integer> iterator = list.iterator(); 
        //аналогично iterateAndSet(array, ()->(int) (8 * Math.random())); разница в том, что теперь элементы в массив добавляются не рандомные,
        //а из отсортированной ранее колдекции, что гарантирует их упорядоченность в массиве. iterator.next() - вызов этого метода у итератора позволяет
        //получать следующий элемент коллекции один за одним
        iterateAndSet(arr, ()->iterator.next());
        //возвращаем отсортированный массив
        return arr;
    }

    //метод, который позволяет обойти двухмерный массив (перебрать все его элементы подряд)
    //первый аргумент - сам массив. второй агрумент интерфейс  Consumer<Integer>.
    //вложенные друг в друга циклы позволяют обойти массив, а вызов consumer.accept(arr1[j]) применяет к каждому элементу массива
    //определенное действие. действие указано в лямбда-выражении. например здесь - iterate(array, i->out.print(i+" "));
    //i->out.print(i+" ") - таким образом каждый элемент массива i выводится в консоль out.print(i+" ")
    private static void iterate(int[][] arr, Consumer<Integer> consumer) {
        for (int[] arr1 : arr) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) consumer.accept(arr1[j]);
        }
    }
    //метод, который позволяет обойти двухмерный массив (перебрать все его элементы подряд)
    //первый аргумент - сам массив. второй агрумент интерфейс  Supplier<Integer>.
    //вложенные друг в друга циклы позволяют обойти массив, а вызов supplier.get() не принимает никаких параметров (get()), 
    //однако, возвращает Integer (определен Supplier<Integer>). что именно вернется, указано в лямбда-выражении. 
    //например здесь - iterateAndSet(array, ()->(int) (8 * Math.random()));
    //()->(int) (8 * Math.random()) - пустые скобки перед стрелкой, как уже указано, означает, что никаких значений не принимается, 
    //а (8 * Math.random()) возвращает каждый раз рандомное число, которое мпопадает во все элементы массива по очереди (они перебираются в цикле)
    private static void iterateAndSet(int[][] arr, Supplier<Integer> supplier) {
        for (int[] arr1 : arr) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) arr1[j] = supplier.get();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Я пока очень слаб в сфере программирования, и только решил поработать с масссивами. Мне ваш код не понятен

Comment: проблема в том, что ваш код вообще никому не понятен, в том числе и вам (потому как он не работает)... если у вас есть непонимание моего кода, то задавайте вопросы, что именно непонятно, а я попробую объяснить.

Comment: Может поможет, если я добавлю я свой код комментарии того, что я пытался реализовать?

Comment: Например, я не понял ни одной библиотеки, объявленной Вами, я не знаю, и не понимаю.

Comment: я никаких библиотек не добавлял. это все исключительно java core

Comment: алгоритмы сортировки давно придуманы и реализованы, не надо изобретать велосипед. list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()); - сортирует эта строка. просто ваш массив сначала преобразовывается в обычную коллекцию, потом сортируется стандартными средствами, а потом сортированные значения пишутся в массив. все просто

Comment: Вот даже того, что это библиотеки я не знал

Comment: я добавил комментарии, чтобы  облегчить понимание того, что происходит. если и так будет непонятно, то можете задавать уточняющие вопросы, но лучше учить мат.часть. потому как этот код достаточно простой и понятный. вам элементарно не хватает знаний

Comment: Спасибо большое